# Can I use GoogleAPI with refresh_token acquired with Firebase Authentication?

Tags: firebase, google-api, firebase-authentication, google-api-nodejs-client

I use Firebase Authentication.

```js
firebase
  .auth()
  .getRedirectResult()
  .then(async function(result) {
    if (result.credential) {
      const { accessToken, idToken } = result.credential
      const { uid, refreshToken } = result.user

      // save to Firestore
      await firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid)
        .set(
          { accessToken, idToken, refreshToken },
          { merge: true }
        )
    }
  })
```

I use GoogleAPI from FirebaseFunctions.
It's code is work.

```
let oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  'my_client_key',
  'my_client_secret'
)
oauth2Client.setCredentials({
  access_token: accessToken,
  refresh_token: refreshToken
})

const calendar = google.calendar({ version: 'v3', auth: oauth2Client })
const result = await calendar.calendarList.list()
```

However, when AccessToken expires, it will not work.
Return error `invalid_grant`

`refresh_token` doesn't seem to work, what should I do?

I tried `getAccessToken()`, `refreshAccessToken()` but got an `invalid_grant` error for the same...

Comment: Have you found a solution?